# How can I add all the values in array with jolt?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jolt

**input** :

```json
{
  "accounts": {
    "canara": 1,
    "sbi": 0,
    "axis": 1,
    "hdfc": 0
  }
}
```

**expected output** :

```json
{
  "canara": 1,
  "sbi": 0,
  "axis": 1,
  "hdfc": 0,
  "total accounts": 2
}
```

I want the sum of all the accounts to be added in "total accounts". how can I achieve this with jolt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This spec should work:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "accounts": {
        "*": [
          ".&",
          "accountsAccumulator"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "total accounts": "=intSum(@(1,accountsAccumulator))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "accountsAccumulator": null,
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

Have a look at:

- the similar question: [Make Sum in Json Array With JOLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678689/make-sum-in-json-array-with-jolt)
- the modify-overwrite-beta operation examples from the demo app:
  https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#modify-mathFunctions

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution

```
[
 // sum all fields and create a new field
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "accounts": {
        "total accounts": "=intSum(@(1,canara),@(1,sbi),@(1,axis),@(1,hdfc))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    //extract all field of the account
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "accounts": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```